# To do list app with sub tasks and progress bars (with web + Android version)

Tags: todo

I am looking for an app that has a web and an Android version and offers the ability to break a task down into sub tasks and (very important) show the progress in form of a progress bar on BOTH the web and the app version. Preferably with progress in %.

Does anyone here know a reliable app that does that? I would pay for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trello seems to have the requirements that you're looking for in an app. However, i personally recommended using Trello in conjunction with Todoist.  You'll need to go in and tweak things around a bit, but this is the exact system that I've been using for a long time and it works for me.

There are extensions in chrome browser that will show you a progress bar for each Trello project and overall, as well as subtasks.

Most everything of mine goes directly into Todoist, then using IFTTT can auto import days to Trello.

This should definitely do the trick.

Best,
TT